# CreateView + get_absolute_url

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, orm, django-views

I'm trying to use CreateView, here is some problem and I'm stacking it.

```
enter code here
```

First of all, i'm trying to create a post and dynamically fill user field who create post. It save the post but don't save the user:

Image from admin

[image]

```
#views.py

    class PostCreateView(CreateView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'blog/post_create.html'
        fields = ('title', 'slug', 'body',)

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.blog__user = self.request.user
            return super(PostCreateView,self).form_valid(form)

#models.py
```

The second one, i think main problem, i don't use get_absolute_url correctly and I get this problem:

No URL to redirect to.

[image]

But it good works for post_detail.

```
     class Blog(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)


        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username

def create_blog(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_blog = Blog.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'], slug=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_blog, sender=User)

class Post(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, db_index=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug,
                                                'username': self.blog})

#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('<username>/create/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    path('<username>/<str:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),
    path('<username>/', PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list_url'),
    path('<username>/<str:slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),

]
```

I am tried to define get_success_url and I get this: NoReverseMatch

[image]

Please help I am really lost in the clouds!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'blog/post_create.html'
        fields = ('title', 'slug', 'body', 'blog')


        def get_success_url(self):
            return self.post_instance.get_absolute_url()

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.blog.user = self.request.user
            self.post_instance = form.instance
            return super(PostCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, now i get **RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /blog/super/create/ Post has no blog.** and still dont save blog-owner :(

Comment: This way it's work, but i don't wanna to show user to make a choice. How to hide it and fill dynamically, like that self.request.user=blog.user?